# Exclude some paths from search in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide, full-text-search

In my project I use external project `DirectXTK`. I have placed this project in External folder and added to the solution. Now whenever I search for something I get a lot of results from this project, but I don't need them. How can I exclude certain path from search in VS 2013? Thanks.